# Start channel entries after a specified count

Tags: entries, count

I need to display entries starting after the third item (where the count is more than three). This must be easy to do, but I haven't found a parameter for this. I know about the {count} variable, but {if {count} > "3"}, {if count > "3"} or {if "{count}" > "3"} doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there are other reasons why not use

```
{exp:channel:entries offset="3"}
```

Then inside the channel tag use the `{if no_results}...{/if}` to handle no content.

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#offset

Comment: Oh, well that is easy! I knew about offset, but thought that referred to the latest entries, not the earliest!

Comment: All depends how you sort yeah?